# Google cloud MySql saying too many connections

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

We are using Google cloud Sql services, I applied composite index to my table 2 hours ago

after this MySql not taking new connections

It's saying

ERROR 1040 (08004): Too many connections

Why we are getting this error??

How much does it require

Comment: You can run "SHOW PROCESSLIST;" query to see active connections and user generating them.

Answer (score 0):

What service do you buy?

According  to [google pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing)

you can have a package with just 250 Maximum Concurrent Connections.

So check how many do you really have?

How ca we know what service do you use and how?

Comment: we are using D4 package .Every time while adding index to table we are getting this too many connections exception. In normal time we are not getting this exception